# PHP: Show HTML Only On Homepage

Tags: php

I'm having trouble getting a PHP script to work. It doesn't seem to be working accurately. I'm trying to make a script to only show HTML or Javascript on the homepage only. This script will be used for multiple things. I did google this, but most answers are for WP. This is vanilla PHP.

Here's what I used:

```
<!-- Add Only On The Homepage Or Else -->
<?php

    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if($currentpage=="/" || $currentpage=="/index.php" || $currentpage=="" ) {

        echo '
            <header id="main-header" class="home">
        ';
    }

    else {

        echo '
            <header id="main-header">
        ';
    }

?>
```

The results are that it shows the content of else, even though it's the homepage. I tested it on "/" and "/index.php".

Comment: Try echoing the value of $currentPage before using it in the if. I suspect it's not set to what you think it is

Comment: worked fine for me

Comment: what is $currentpage returning when you print it to the screen? I tested your code on my localhost and it seems to work fine. Check your currentpage variable and adjust your if statement to reflect it.

Comment: `echo $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` what does it show you when you run it from the script you're executing from?

Comment: $currentpage = /website/workspace/hm-external-site/index.php This looks right to me?

Comment: `/website/workspace/hm-external-site/index.php` and you're checking for `/index.php`, *no love here*.

Comment: OK, I fixed it. It works now.

Comment: *Another happy ending* ;-) should delete the question though.

Answer (score 1):

I commonly use this snippet:

index.php

```
if (preg_match('/^m\.[^\/]+(\/(\?.*|index\.html(\?.*)?)?)?$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    readfile('index.html');
} else {
    // Your framework bootstrapper or your own logic
}
```